# Fatal PHP Data Objects (PDO) Error - But PDO is enabled?

Tags: apache, php, cpanel

I recently switched website hosts, however with the new hosts, we are encountering some PDO problems. Everything indicates that PDO is enabled on my server, however, when I test it through php, with a script that I created using this stack overflow question, all indicators indicate that PDO is not in fact enabled on my server.

However, when I look at my php.ini file in my root directory, I see

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"
zend_extension="/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so"
extension = "suhosin.so"
extension = "pdo.so"
extension = "pdo_sqlite.so"
extension = "pdo_mysql.so"
```

and the .htaccess in that directory contains

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/shortcut/public_html
```

my results from the [phpinfo()](http://shortcutcentral.org/info.php) command seem to show some PDO things, but I can't actually distinguish if it is activated or not.

The results from the [following script](http://shortcutcentral.org/pdotest.php) indicate PHP data objects'PDO' is not working (and it's definitely affecting some of my other scripts which are now broken), however everything else indicates that it should be working. I have contacted my hosts and they are telling me that the PDO module is already activated.

```
Hi Adam,

Thank you for getting back to us.
pdo module already enabled in our server. Please have a look at snippet.
=============================
root@kipling [/home]# php -m | grep pdo
pdo_mysql<br />
pdo_sqlite<br />
=============================
```

The script which tells me that nothing is working contains the following:

```
<?php if ( extension_loaded('pdo') ) {
    echo 'PDO extension is loaded';
}
if (class_exists('PDO')){
    echo 'The PDO Class exists';
}
echo '<br>PHP is working';
 ?>
```

I'm at a complete loss to do, and don't even know how to begin tackling this problem. We're also encountering some suhosin.so errors as well:

```
[16-Jul-2014 10:43:00 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/suhosin.so: undefined symbol: output_globals in Unknown on line 0
```

If that is related to this at all. (I don't know if the suhosin.so is breaking anything, so it's hard to say)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the PHP versions are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly perform a check if there is any php.ini file under your account. Rename it as it might conflict with the original server's php.ini.